# If Jesus retained Omniscience whilst incarnate why is He surprised by Nathaniel’s Response?

Tags: john, new-testament

This is an curious passage to me, that seems at first to agree that Jesus retained His Omniscience because at first

> “Yeshua saw Natan’el coming toward him and remarked about him, “Here’s a true son of Isra’el — nothing false in him!” Natan’el said to him, “How do you know me?” Yeshua answered him, “Before Philip called you, when you were under the fig tree, I saw you.””
>   ‭‭Yochanan (Jhn)‬ ‭1:47-48‬ ‭CJB‬‬

So whilst the text doesn’t explain by what means Jesus saw Nathaniel, whether physically, or in the spirit through some vision

Nathaniel responds

> “Natan’el said, “Rabbi, you are the Son of God! You are the King of Isra’el!””
>   ‭‭Yochanan (Jhn)‬ ‭1:49‬ ‭CJB‬‬

Why then does Jesus sound shocked and/or surprised. He says

> “Yeshua answered him, “you believe all this just because I told you I saw you under the fig tree? You will see greater things than that!””
>   ‭‭Yochanan (Jhn)‬ ‭1:50‬ ‭CJB‬‬

Why so surprised if you already knew who your disciples were going to be and prayed all night to know which twelve disciples to choose and where to find them?

Comment: There is no 'shock' or 'surprise' indicated by either the narrative or the spoken words. These are just statements of fact or reasonable questions. I think you are imposing suppositions on the text.

Comment: How do you read that phrase “you believe because I said I saw you?” and think fact? It’s not a rhetorical question. It’s a reasonable question to ask if you were not expecting such a response from such little information “I saw you under a fig tree”. Yes I’m imposing supposition, human emotions and logical reactions to unexpected choices. But I’m open if you have a different way of reading this question for you to share Nigel. I might be overlooking an angle that is obvious to you but not to me. Please enlighten my ignorance.

Comment: Christ's words are equivalent to saying *(if) you believe all this (merely) because I told you I saw you under the fig tree, (what will you do when) you will see (even) greater things than that ?*

Comment: The question remains even with that variant, why would Jesus be surprised if He retained Omniscience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Jesus did not use His resources as the Son of God. **Omnipotence**, **Omnisicence** & **Omnipresence** were the things ( at least some of the things ) He **emptied Himself** of when He incarnated.

> [Philippians 2:6-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%202%3A6-8&version=ESV) English Standard Version (ESV)
>
> 6 who, though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with
>   God a thing to be grasped,[a] 7 **but emptied himself**, by taking the
>   form of a servant,[b] being born in the likeness of men. 8 And being
>   found in human form, he humbled himself by becoming obedient to the
>   point of death, even death on a cross.

He lived as the **Son of man** wihout using these privileges he possessed as the **Son of God** casting himself upon the Father's enablement for everything including:

**1. knowledge**,

> [Mark 13:32](https://biblehub.com/mark/13-32.htm) “But concerning that day or that hour, no one knows,
>   not even the angels in heaven, **nor the Son**, but only the Father.

**2. action**

> [John 5:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%202%3A6-8&version=ESV) So Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, **the
>   Son can do nothing of his own accord**, **but only what he sees the Father
>   doing.** For whatever the Father does, that the Son does likewise.
>
> [John 14:10](https://biblehub.com/john/14-10.htm) Do you not believe that I am in the Father and the
>   Father is in me? The words that I say to you I do not speak on my own
>   authority, but **the Father who dwells in me does his works**.

**3. power**

Jesus had the power to ressurect himself but He was resurrected by the Father and by the Holy Spirit

> [Romans 8:11](https://biblehub.com/romans/8-11.htm) T**he Spirit of God, who raised Jesus from the dead**,
>   lives in you. And just as **God raised Christ Jesus from the dead**, he
>   will give life to your mortal bodies by this same Spirit living within
>   you.

There is a mystery about these things. So it cannot be fully explained in words on the details on how He did them.

> [1 Timothy 3:16](https://biblehub.com/kjv/1_timothy/3-16.htm) And without controversy **great is the mystery** of
>   godliness: **God was manifest in the flesh**, justified in the Spirit,
>   seen of angels, preached unto the Gentiles, believed on in the world,
>   received up into glory.

Comment: Good answer, as far as it goes. Plus 1. The kenosis,(or self-emptying) of Jesus is--at best--difficult to explain and understand. Hymn writer Charles Wesley gave it a shot when he wrote that Jesus "emptied himself of all but love
And bled for Adam's helpless race." A great sentiment, to be sure. The "flashes of divinity" which are apparent in the narrative of Jesus's ministry seem to indicate (to me at least), that Jesus did not empty himself of everything but love. Yes, you can attribute the miracles to Jesus's obedience to his Father's will, but to do so does not make the miracles any less

Comment: a "God thing," in my opinion. The miracles were a collaborative effort of the triune God. Jesus definitely exercised the prerogatives of deity by healing people, raising people from the dead, and forgiving their sins. Perhaps an understanding of the self-emptying of Jesus requires such concepts as "veiling his glory," "limiting his divine prerogatives," and "a meeting of minds between Father and Son." The only thing we cannot let go of as a non-negotiable given is that Jesus was and always will be God in the flesh, the God-Man, fully God and fully Man. Right?

Comment: Yes He was fully Man ( refered by the title "Son of Man" ) & fully God ( refered by the title "Son of God ) at the same time from the begining of virgin birth. And it continues like that for ever except for the fact that now He has a glorified body.

Comment: These two natures are united without mixture, confusion, separation, or division. We distinguish, without separating, our Lord’s human nature from His divine nature. Source: [The Natures of Christ](https://www.ligonier.org/learn/devotionals/natures-christ/)

Comment: @SijuGeorge [[ Books and letter on the way. Apologies for administrative delay. Regards, Nigel.]]